# Unable to show the navbar in moblile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am stick in responsive design which i am doing in laravel. The below code works in a normal view but in the nav bar is hidden in a mobile view. I checked with the javascript function but cannot troubleshoot the problem. 
This is my html code

```
 <div class="container">
      <nav>
            <ul>
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
              <li><a href="#">Our School</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Key Features</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Infrastructure</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Fee System</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Commitment & Objectives</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Rules & Regulations</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Hostel Management</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Facilities</a> </li>
              <li><a href="#">News & Events</a> </li>
              <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a> </li>

              <li><a href="#">Student Zone</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Mobile Menu Area Start -->
<div class="mobile-menu-area" style="display:none">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="mobile-menu">
          <nav id="dopdown">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a>
              <li><a href="#">Our School</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="">Key Features</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Infrastructure</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Fee System</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Commitment & Objectives</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Rules & Regulations</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">Hostel Management</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Our Facilities</a> </li>
              <li><a href="#">News & Events</a> </li>
              <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a> </li>
              <li><a href="#">Downloads</a> </li>
              <li><a href="#">Student Zone</a> </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js code

```
 $('nav#dropdown').meanmenu({siteLogo: "<a href='{{asset('client/home')}}' class='logo-mobile-menu'><img src='images/logo.png' alt='unable' /></a>"});
new WOW().init();
    $.scrollUp({
    scrollText: '<i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>',
    easingType: 'linear',
    scrollSpeed: 900,
    animation: 'fade'
});
```

In the mobile view it doesn't show the header file.

Comment: Have you had a look at the CSS styles to see whether a `nav` is hidden on some breakpoint?

Comment: I had checked the css styles and did't found such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  id which you gave in `<nav id ='dopdown'>` and which you are using in js function `$(;nav#dropdown)` is different.Tt may be the cause of your problem. Plese try this once.

Comment: Always focus on Id name which is responsible for simple mistake.